# How to turn an *.RDS file into a *.FEATHER file?

Tags: python, r, pandas, feather

I am trying to covert an `*.rds` file in R into a `*.feather` file for use in Python.

```
library(feather)
data = readRDS("file.rds")
write_feather(data,"file.feather")
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
> write_feather(data,"file.feather")
Error: `x` must be a data frame
```

How can I turn the `*.rds` file/matrix into a `*.feather` file to read with Pandas (or any other Pandas-compatible file that can handle a 24000*24000 matrix)?

[image]

Comment: It appears that your data is not in data.frame format. Try `as.data.frame(as.matrix(data))`.

Comment: This seems to have worked and should be an answer! :) At least there was an export. I am trying the import now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coerce matrix obeject to data.frame object:

```
library(feather)
data = readRDS("file.rds")
as.data.frame(as.matrix(data))
write_feather(data,"file.feather")
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I had to run `pip install pyarrow` before the import in Python via `pd.read_feather("file.feather")` but that was of course not a problem!

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple in fact, you can convert only dataframes and you have to name your file:
Use:

```
data = data.frame(data)
```

Now use the function and it should work:

```
write_feather(data,"file.feather")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does not work unfortunately. `data = data.frame(data)` returns `Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : cannot coerce class ‘structure("dgeMatrix", package = "Matrix")’ to a data.frame`.